# MATLAB parse OS-specific path

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I am running a MATLAB project, which is shared by several users, some running Windows and some running Linux.

In some of the scripts, I need to access files which are in external directories, and which I do not want to add to the MATLAB path.

To accommodate both Linux and Windows, I need to be able to determine the type of OS I'm running, and to set the directory separator accordingly ('\' for Windows, '/' for Linux).

I tried

```
os = getenv('OS')
```

(which I saw in some official guide),but it returns an empty string.

I could check the first character of 'pwd', but that's pretty ugly, and I expect that there should be something simpler.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use correct directory separator you don't need to write code to handle different operating systems. `filesep` gives you the correct directory separator.

```
My1stDir = 'Year2012';
My2ndDir = 'Feb';
My3rdDir = 'Day03';

MyDir = [ 'mydata', filesep, My1stDir, filesep, My2ndDir, filesep, My3rdDir ];
```

In Linux you'll get:

```
MyDir =
     mydata/Year2012/Feb/Day03
```

In Windows you'll get:

```
MyDir =
     mydata\Year2012\Feb\Day03
```

Comment: You may wish to look into `fullfile`