# Easy way to make "system" command independent of OS

Tags: matlab, cmd, operating-system

My work place has an extensive script library that uses plenty of system commands to make directories.  Previously, all this work was done on Linux so everything is hardcoded with forwarded slashes "/", but we now want to make it windows compatible.

At the moment, trying to make a directory with `system('mkdir ../dir')` throws an error because Windows command line uses back slashes "\" for making directories.

Is there an easy way to tell windows to treat the hardcoded forward slashes as back slashes?

My only thought right now is to do a `if(ispc)` command and set a variable to "\" or "/" accordingly, but I want to know if there are alternatives.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB parse OS-specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760327/matlab-parse-os-specific-path)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably a way to automate the procedure, but I'd recommend a one-time general solution. Unless we're talking about a thousand cases, you should be able to do it by hand.

The [**`filesep`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) function is the dedicated function for this purpose, it will always return the correct file seperator for every OS. So just go to your files and replace all `\` with `' filesep '` (probaly some `[...]` are required as well).

Comment: This is definitely better than the way I was approaching it, so thank you!

We're talking around 100 or so cases in many different files.  Doable by hand so I guess I'll have to take this route.